# Matrices with given characteristic polynomial are similar iff the characteristic polynomial have no repeated roots

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

All $n$ x $n$ matrices with characteristic polynomial $f(x)$ are similar iff $f(x)$ has no repeated roots in F[x].

My attempt: If f has no repeated matrices, all such matrices are diagonlisable hence similar. The other direction I haven't been able to do. Here's my line of thinking: if two matrices are similar, they have the same rational canonical form hence the same invariant factors(?). Thus they have the same minimal polynomial, but I am not sure why the characteristic and minimal polynomials are equal.

Comment: Do You know the Jordan normal form of matrices?

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes.

Comment: then You have different  possibilities for the Jordan normal form in the case of multiple roots, say for a root $\lambda$ of multiplicity 2 You can have Jordan blocks $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ which are obviously not similar

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: You´re welcome!